# node.js, mongo quick way to hold unique number

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, guid

I want to let mongo hold an incrementing number for me such that I can call that number and then generate a string from it.

```
x = 1e10
x.toString(36).substring(2,7)

>>'dqpds'
```

I have a way to increment the number every time I call it from mongo

```
db.counter.update({ _id: 1 }, { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, {upsert: true}, 
    function(err, val){
    //...
})
```

But I want to set the number to something like 1e10 at the beginning such that I get a 5 character long string, But I would rather not have something more than one call to the database.

How to I set a default value for the upsert in mongo. Or do you have a more efficient way of generating a unique 5 - 6 character string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need a unique id which is not necessarily sequential, you can use the first part of [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/).

From the above document there is a description:

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> ```
> a 4-byte timestamp,
> a 3-byte machine identifier,
> a 2-byte process id, and
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
> ```

So you can do like this:

```
x = ObjectId().toString().subString(0,4)
```

This approach doesn't involve database IO, so the performance would be better. If you want to be more sure about its uniqueness, add the last 2 bytes of the counter to make a 6 character one.

Comment: Yes, I think I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in MongoDB.

You use the [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) command and it's described in detail in exactly the context you are looking for here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: that is for an auto incrementing field across multiple entries, I only want one entry in the collection, also that doesn't solve the issue of the default value I think. The workaround I have at the moment is to check the db on app start up, But ids like something more succinct

Comment: this is for one entry. And it can start out as any value you want (if you check it on startup, aren't you going to have it be recycling every time you restart the app?)